# How do I get printer resolution in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

In order to place objects correctly on the page I need to get the printer resolution. How do I do that in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size is passed to your subclass of `UIPrintPageRenderer` in the `func drawContentForPageAtIndex(_ index: Int, inRect contentRect: CGRect)` method.

If you don't already have a renderer, you will need to create one. Then set it as the `printPageRenderer` on your `UIPrintInteractionController`.